# Haskell error with modules

Tags: haskell

I had Haskell platform installed on my computer and it worked fine until today. Today, when I wanted to load a file in prelude I got this error:

```
Could not find module `Test.QuickCheck'
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I uninstalled Haskell platform and then I installed it again, but got the same error. Can someone help me?

Comment: It seems that Test.Quickcheck file does not exist where you think it does

Answer (score 0):

Seems like QuickCheck is not installed. Try to install it again through Cabal and don't forget to update your package list before you do:

```
cabal update    
cabal install QuickCheck
```